# Entity Framework Guid to String with joined tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I've tried a lot of suggestions online, but nothing has worked.  I'm trying to return values from a database using Entity Framework, but my TransactionId is a GUID.  The code throws an error trying to convert a GUID to string.  Here is what I had originally:

```
var entityVerification = from tl in _context.TransactionLogs
join ts in _context.TransactionStatuses on tl.GUTransactionId equals ts.GUTransactionId
where tl.ExternalTargetAccountNumber == accountNumber
orderby ts.PostedTime descending
select new TransactionHistoryEntity
{
   TransactionId = tl.GUTransactionId,
   SourceAccountNumber = tl.ExternalSourceAccountNumber,
   ActionCode = tl.ActionCode,
   Amount = tl.Amount,
   CurrencyCode = tl.CurrencyCode,
   PostedTime = ts.PostedTime,
   StatusCode = ts.StatusCode
};

return await entityVerification.ToListAsync();
```

I've tried creating a query object that I can then convert the TransactionId into a string later, but this throws the same error:

```
var transactionLogs = _context.TransactionLogs;
var transactionStatus = _context.TransactionStatuses;

var test = transactionLogs.ToList().Join(transactionStatus, ts => ts.GUTransactionId, tl => tl.GUTransactionId,
(tl, ts) => new
{
   ts.GUTransactionId,
   tl.ExternalSourceAccountNumber,
   tl.ActionCode,
   tl.Amount,
   tl.CurrencyCode,
   ts.PostedTime,
   ts.StatusCode
});
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
   at lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.BufferlessMoveNext(DbContext _, Boolean buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Aggregate.cs:line 120
   at DataManagement.Data.Repository.FTTransact.TransactionLogRepository.GetTransactionHistory(String accountNumber) in D:\Source\DayforceSpecialProjects\Fintech\Platform\DataManagement\Data\Repository\FTTransact\TransactionLogRepository.cs:line 39
```

Context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionLogEntity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("TransactionLog");
                entity.HasKey("GUTransactionId");

                entity.Property(e => e.GlbGuProgramId)
                    .HasColumnName("GLB_GUProgramId")
                    .HasColumnType("bigint");

                entity.Property(e => e.GlbGuProductId)
                    .HasColumnName("GLB_GUProductId")
                    .HasColumnType("bigint");

                entity.Property(e => e.Amount)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18,10)");

                entity.Property(e => e.CurrencyCode)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(10)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Units)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18,10)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ValuePerUnit)
                    .HasColumnType("decimal(18,10)");

                entity.Property(e => e.TransactionReceivedTime)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.TargetPostingTime)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.RequestTransactionId)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(128)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ExternalTargetAccountNumber)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(128)");

                entity.Property(e => e.ExternalSourceAccountNumber)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(128)");

                entity.Property(e => e.TargetRegGuAccountId)
                    .HasColumnName("TargetREG_GUAccountId")
                    .HasColumnType("bigint");

                entity.Property(e => e.SourceRegGuAccountId)
                    .HasColumnName("SourceREG_GUAccountId")
                    .HasColumnType("bigint");

                entity.Property(e => e.ActionCode)
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(64)");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TransactionStatusEntity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("TransactionStatus");
                entity.HasKey("GUTransactionStatusId");

                entity.Property(e => e.GUTransactionId)
                    .HasColumnType("guid");

                entity.Property(e => e.PostedTime)
                    .HasColumnType("datetime");

                entity.Property(e => e.StatusCode)
                    .HasColumnType("nchar(10)");
            });
```

Entites:

```
public class TransactionStatusEntity
    {
        public string GUTransactionStatusId { get; set; }
        public string GUTransactionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostedTime { get; set; }
        public string StatusCode { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class TransactionLogEntity
    {
        public string GUTransactionId { get; set; }
        public long GlbGuProgramId { get; set; }
        public long GlbGuProductId { get; set; }
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public decimal Units { get; set; }
        public decimal? ValuePerUnit { get; set; }
        public DateTime TransactionReceivedTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime TargetPostingTime { get; set; }
        public string RequestTransactionId { get; set; }
        public string ExternalTargetAccountNumber { get; set; }
        public string ExternalSourceAccountNumber { get; set; }
        public long? TargetRegGuAccountId { get; set; }
        public long? SourceRegGuAccountId { get; set; }
        public string ActionCode { get; set; }
    }
```

I just need to convert the GUID to a string.  Seems like it should be pretty simple, but it's causing a lot of headache.

Comment: Which are the GUIDs, and which the Strings?

Comment: What's the *actual* error? Post the full exception text, including the call stack, the table schemas and the classes. If you get an error about a conversion to a string you should try to find out what's wrong, not try to cover it up. Most likely one of the properties is *not* a Guid. Or the database field is a string instead of a GUID and contains invalid data. Or a parameter you passed is a string that can't be parsed as a GUID. Using `ToJoin` doesn't fix anything, it loads *everything* in memory instead of joining data on the server

Comment: It could be that `TransactionLogs.GUTransactionId` is a GUID and `TransactionStatuses.GUTransactionId` a string or vice versa. It could be that `TransactionHistoryEntity.TransactionId` is a GUID but `GUTransactionId` is a string containing something that can't be parsed as a GUID.

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't need any JOINs. It's the ORM's job to create the JOIN statements from the relations between the entities and the context's configuration. The `TransactionLog` entity should have a `Status` property or `Statuses` collection, depending on the type of the relation. You shouldn't need to write anything more than `context.TransactionLogs.Where(log=>log....).Select(log=>new TransactionHistoryEntity { PostedTime=log.Status.PostedTime,....});`

Comment: The error message is as follows: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.  I updated the question above to include the stack trace.  The GUID is GUTransactionID.

Comment: @AndreasMassey Why don't you just use the .NET `Guid` type in your application?

Comment: @jcruz is right. Use the `Guid` type and this will solve your problem because GUIDs and strings are not inherently interchangeable. If you don't want to keep calling `.ToString()` every time, then add an additional read-only property to the class that does the string conversion and decorate with `[NotMapped]`.